# Как обратиться к константе класса если объект хранится в статическом свойстве класса?

Tags: php, классы

```
class Calc
{
    const PROP = TRUE;
}

class PHP_Unit_Test
{
    static protected $testModel;

    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        self::$testModel = new Calc();
    }

    public function test_some_method()
    {
        // вот тут как мне получить значение константы класса Calc?
        // приведенная ниже строка конечно неправильная, она для демонстрации
        self::$testModel::PROP;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фактически, ваша задача сводится к получению константы класса из экземпляра этого класса. Самый простой способ состоит в использовании функции [`get_class`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-class.php):

```
class Calc
{
    const PROP = true;
}

$c = new Calc();
$class_name = get_class($c);
var_dump($class_name::PROP); // bool(true)
```

Работающий [пример на IDEOne](https://ideone.com/mqJ4zQ).

Для вашего конкретного случая:

```
// ...
public function test_some_method() 
{
    $class_name = get_class(self::$testModel);
    var_dump($class_name::PROP);
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно поступить следующим образом. Сформировать строку "Calc::PROP" и передать ее функции `constant()`, которая вернет значение константы класса

```
<?php
class Calc
{
    const PROP = TRUE;
}

class PHP_Unit_Test
{
    static protected $testModel;

    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        self::$testModel = new Calc();
    }

    public function test_some_method()
    {
        // вот тут как мне получить значение константы класса Calc?
        // приведенная ниже строка конечно неправильная, она для демонстрации
        //self::$testModel::PROP;
        return constant(get_class(self::$testModel)."::PROP");
    }
}

$obj = new PHP_Unit_Test();
$obj->setUpBeforeClass();
echo $obj->test_some_method();
```

Comment: На самом деле, функция `constant` совсем не нужна.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, без нее не получить значение константы.

Comment: Это вам только так кажется. Пруф: https://ideone.com/mqJ4zQ

Comment: Да, согласен, если оформить имя класса в качестве отдельной переменной.